# Magento 2: I need to change template for different categories

Tags: magento2, layout, category-view

I need to change the template for subcategories(like able to assign any category) and `list.phtml` is fine. But need to change template for random categories.

Any one have solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by template? Do you need different layout or different theme?

Comment: different layout

Comment: @SukumarGorai Do you have solution for this?

Comment: If you want to use different list.phtml then you can try the solution of HoangHieu. If any issue let me know here.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Manage category in Admin
- In **Design** tab you will find **Theme** dropdown
- Select your theme from there and this will apply to that category

Answer (score 3):

I have three options for you if you are a developer.

**Option 1.** You can use xml layout such as named `catalog_category_view_id_[Cat Id].xml` to change list.phtml template.

**Option 2.** Add new category attribute using setup upgrade

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'custom_product_list_template',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Category custom template',
            'input' => 'select',
            'sort_order' => 600,
            'source' => 'Namespace\CategoryCustom\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Templates',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => null,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Design',
            'backend' => ''
        ]
    );
```

**Namespace\CategoryCustom\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Templates**
 extends **\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource**

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if ($this->_options === null) {
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __('None'), 'value' => ''],
            ['label' => __('Custom Template'), 'value' => 'category_custom_template_file'],
        ];
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
```

**Namespace/CategoryCustom/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<fieldset name="display_settings">
    <field name="custom_product_list_template">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\CategoryCustom\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Templates</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ground Custom Template</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

**Add event observer to add layout update to events.xml**

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_product_list_template" instance="Namespace\CategoryCustom\Observer\ProcessProduclistTemplate"/>
</event>
```

Observer class **\Namespace\CategoryCustom\Observer\ProcessProduclistTemplate**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if($observer->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){
        $currentCategory = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        if(is_object($currentCategory) && $currentCategory->getId()){
            $handle = $currentCategory->getData('custom_product_list_template') ?: '';
            if($handle){
                $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handle);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

After that custom you layout in category_custom_template_file.xml

**Option 3.** Create new static block -> assign it to category and change the config of the category from (Display CMS and Product -> CMS).

Comment: I don't want to add catalog_category_view_id_[Cat Id].xml     Id wise.

Comment: Let use option 2 and 3